# How to overcome TLS1.2 requirement on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl

We have a legacy product running on a Win2003 Server. It makes a call to a third party service to allow the user to make secure payments. We have been notified that the third-party will be switching to TLS 1.2. Windows Server 2003 does not support TLS 1.2. For reasons beyond the scope of this question, we cannot easily move the code to a new server, and we are hesitant to risk an OS upgrade to the production machine. I'm looking for the most simplistic solution to buy us some time while we work towards moving this product to the cloud. I'm toying with the following ideas.

1. Use a proxy of some sort to bridge between TLS 1.0, and 1.2 (if possible, I'm not sure how to approach this.)
2. Create a service that routes requests/response, and modify the host file in the server to direct to the new endpoint.

I can't imagine I am the first to deal with this issue - and would wrather not re-invent the wheel. I'm experienced enough that is someone gives me a general approach with some key words, I can work through the rest.

Question: What approach would allow code running on a Windows 2003 server to continue to call an existing endpoint after it's upgrade to TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's high time a "secure" payment service upgrades its TLS 1.0, this update is long overdue.

I see these options:

1. clone server (if possible to virtual machine), try upgrade offline
2. set up an SSL proxy - the TLS 1.0 socket needs to be terminated and the data piped into a TLS 1.2 socket; this will most likely include some DNS manipulation and possibly require using a custom CA certificate

Comment: Thank you Zac -- we tried cloning and upgrading, it didn't go so well. I'll explore the SSL proxy. I appreciate your taking the time to answer.